# Writing a JavaScript Library: how to authorize methods?

Tags: javascript, rest, authorization

Okay, the title of this topic is really stupid - but I am not able to sum it up in a better way than that. So here is more detailed version of my problem:

I am creating a small JavaScript library that enables developers to send strings on custom  events to a dedicated server (url defined in the library). Lets say the library is called "testLib", the developer that uses this library could write something like this:

```
function success() {
   testLib.send("Everything OK");
}
```

So everytime this success function is called, a REST call (POST-request) is made to the server that is definded inside the library. So far, thats no problem.

But the ugly thing is that everyone with firebug or similar could call these "testLib.send()" method too. Thats really ugly, because the hole sense behind this library is to track **only** the events that the developer has defined. Of course, the server will take care of the basic validation (origin check, API key,..), but still: One could start firebug and just call the "testLib.send" method.

Is there any chance to build an authorization mechanism that prevent the "firebug user" from sending rest calls via the predefined library methods?

Comment: by **anyone** you mean anonymous users or authenticated/authorised ones?

Comment: Anonymous. Like if you write your one website and use this library. For example, the testLib.send() method is called everytime a user clicks a specific button of your website.
Maybe you can look at it as some kind of advanced google analytics feature that not only track the page visits (and such things), but custom defined events.

Comment: I edited my answer to include some more information that you may find valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing practical.

The library runs on the client's computer. You have no control over that. They can edit the JS to their heart's content. They can bypass it entirely and send hand-crafted HTTP requests if they want (or write a quick script to bomb the server with requests).

Any real protection you implement has to be on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Writing Javascript is like writing open source. FireBug is but one of the plugins which can get into your script, modify it on the fly, invoke methods, access variables, etc. In fact, you don't have to go that far: The Javascript console in most browsers contains a quick eval input box. Because Javascript is an interpreter, anyone can get in and do as they wish.

You have two options which might make it a tad more difficult (though certainly NOT impassable):

1) Obfuscation and/or packing the script, when you are done - though most obfuscators can easily be bypassed
2) Having your methods check who called them - have a look at arguments.callee.caller for that. That said, this might run into problem in strict mode.

Your best bet is to repeat any validation in the server side, as you say. If the server side validation fails - this actually tells you something: Someone deliberately bypassed your Javascript, and you can deal with him accordingly.

Hope this helps

TG

Answer (score 2):

### Authenticating users

If you application authenticates a user when the page loads, then every request from the client side will come along with authentication cookie so basically you will be able to detect who the sender is.

### Obfuscation and private closures

But if you'd like to prevent programmatic access to that particular function that your best bet is function closure to make that function private and inaccessible and some code obfuscation that prevents people from plainly rewriting the whole stuff. One great obfuscation is the [Javascript packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) with Base62 enabled.

But this kind of things will of course obfuscate your library, but publicly accessible functions would still be accessible.

### Preventing anonymous users

However. If you'd like anonymous users to prevent from sending stuff to your server you can't do that really, but you can identify unauthorised requests, by having your functions to require some sort of a registration key that your developers (real users) would have, but anons wouldn't.

And maybe some other resources found on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+authentication) may help just a well. Just to scratch the surface. XHR for instance allows users to send username and password to authenticate the request which may be exactly what you're after. But you should know better since you have the library design not us.

Answer (score 1):

No. Because javascript runs on the client side, there's nothing you can do to prevent someone from reading what the client is executing and executing it themselves. There are things you can do to obfuscate your calls, but this is [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) - and shouldn't be relied on. If you want to make sure that ONLY the developer is making calls to your API, they would need to do it on the server side.